# Downsize bunch of "if", "elseif". (16 possibilities)

Tags: php, function, optimization, if-statement, reduce

I've thought of how to make this easier/cleaner/better for the hosting (I guess my method not server-friendly, although I'm not sure).

My purpose: reduce (if possible) the "if" part. That part checks which dropbdown boxes have been changed from "empty" (it's actually "all" but it could be changed to empty if it's better for something), and applies it to show only the users that meet those conditions (home university, host university, location and/or nationality. This is the only easy/basic way I've been able to create.

I have this function:

```
function get_user_listing($curauth) {
  global $post;
  $concat = wpu_concat_single();
  // These get the values from the plugin Cimy User Extra Fields:
  $homeuni=get_cimyFieldValue($curauth->ID,'homeuni');
  $hostuni=get_cimyFieldValue($curauth->ID,'hostuni');
  $location=get_cimyFieldValue($curauth->ID,'location');
  $nationality=get_cimyFieldValue($curauth->ID,'nationality');
  // These get the values from a dropdown form in the page:
  $selectedhomeuni = $_POST['homeuni'];
  $selectedhostuni = $_POST['hostuni'];  
  $selectedlocation = $_POST['location'];
  $selectednationality = $_POST['nationality'];

//This is the code that has to be run every time to display every user info:
include '/home/u548205287/public_html/wp-content/themes/Trim/profilescode.php';

// I set an initial page that runs the code with no conditions because with 
the form, the page would look empty until the form is submitted once:
if(is_page(806)) {return $html;} 

else{
if($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {return $html;} // The possibilities with each dropdown start here. If "all" (the "empty" one) is selected, nothing changes and all are displayed.
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni) {return $html;}}  // If any dropdown is selected, its value acts as a filter and only the users with that info are shown.
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($hostuni==$selectedhostuni) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($location==$selectedlocation) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $hostuni==$selectedhostuni) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $location==$selectedlocation) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $hostuni==$selectedhostuni && $location==$selectedlocation) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $hostuni==$selectedhostuni && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $location==$selectedlocation && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni != "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($homeuni==$selectedhomeuni && $hostuni==$selectedhostuni && $location==$selectedlocation && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality == "all") {if($hostuni==$selectedhostuni && $location==$selectedlocation) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation == "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($hostuni==$selectedhostuni && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni != "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($hostuni==$selectedhostuni && $location==$selectedlocation && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
elseif($selectedhomeuni == "all" && $selectedhostuni == "all" && $selectedlocation != "all" && $selectednationality != "all") {if($location==$selectedlocation && $nationality==$selectednationality) {return $html;}}
}
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing all the if's. I'm sure there is. Thank you :)

Comment: Man, this code is *scary*!

Comment: oh dear...what a mess

Comment: If you add some tabs and linebreaks, you might get some help

Comment: Sorry... I do what I can... My knowledge is basic.

Comment: Speaking of server-friendness though, this code is all right.

Comment: Can you add a paragraph in your question describing what you want your code to accomplish, specifically? There may be a better solution than what you currently have implemented (not just the `if` statements, but the logic that comes before that)

Comment: I'd probably go with nested ifs so that the variables are checked only once or twice in the scheme of things. It will make the code much longer, but it *might* be more efficient.

Comment: user20232359723568423357842364 I've reformatted it a bit in the first part, although linebreaking the if's makes it look even worse  // ಠ_ಠ I've added it ("My purpose"). I hope it's clear :)
//
@aynber I thought about nested if's, but I wasn't sure how to accomplish it. However, I'd like to keep the code as short as possible, if it's server-friendly as Your Common Sense says, for future reading easyness (it may be a mess/scary, but it can be easily understood by a non-coder person, can't it? It may not be me the person to maintain it in the future). :)  [Comments can't be formatted, great]

Comment: @user2657796 - It looks like you're checking the four variables to see if they're set to 'all'. If any of them are not, then you're checking the value against the one from `get_cimyFieldValue`. In which case, you can do something like:

Comment: `if(in_array($selectedhomeuni ("all", $home_uni)) && in_array($selectedhostuni ("all", $host_uni)) &&....`

Comment: @andrewsi I check if they are or aren't set to "all", and those which are not set to "all", I set them to use the value given by get_cimyFieldValue (This part I never understood, because it looks like a checking/comparison, not a set which I believe would require a single =, but this is the way it works with this plugin). It would be great to get rid of the "all" part and just checking and setting those which are actually a name, and shorten up the code. Would making the "all" empty help? (I've tried, but doesn't change a bit).

Comment: Oh, and @andrewsi, I didn't understand what your code changes, isn't it very similar? Thank you

Comment: @antonio1475 - it means you can use a single if statement, rather than 16 different ones. On the other hand - what is your code supposed to return if none of the statements evaluate to true?

Comment: @andrewsi Oh, in that case I'll try it, although I'm not sure I know what to do. If all are set to "all" (the default selected value), all users are shown (the return $html which displays every user is run). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just say what you mean:

```
if(  ($selectedhomeuni == "all" || $selectedhomeuni == $homeuni)
  && ($selectedhostuni == "all" || $selectedhostuni == $hostuni)
  && ($selectedlocation == "all" || $selectedlocation == $location)
  && ($selectednationality == "all" || $selectednationality == $nationality)
  )
{
  return $html;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! That seems to work perfectly! Could you tell me what the || are so I can search more about it and learn? (Google doesn't recognize the ||). Thank you :)

Comment: @antonio1475: the [*`&&` means "and", and the `||` means "or".*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)